# Identify this Avenir or Benton Sans-looking typeface

Tags: font-identification

[image: screenshot]

It's oh-so-very close to Avenir, but is just a little different from the cuts I saw:

[image: Avenir]

I also found it to be close to Benton Sans, but that doesn't quite hold up either (the 'k' shows it here, but the 'G' elsewhere that I'm excluding for the sake of discretion doesn't match either):

[image: Benton Sans]

Any thoughts?

Comment: Unlock is really like Benton Sans and Monotype News Gothic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Interface corp](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/daltonmaag/interface-corp/) family looks close IMHO

[image]

Comment: Good call. The only thing that makes it look "close" rather than identical is the combination of reversed text and anti-aliasing. The tight tracking doesn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

## Found using WhatFontIs.com

**Potential:** Solitaire MVB Pro SemiBold, otherwise could be Lasiver Medium, Workaday

**Unlock your:** Crique Grotesk Display Regular, otherwise Crique Grotesk Regular, Equip Regular

Comment: [Solitaire MVB Bold](http://cl.ly/image/321W1j302e24) - the 'a' is different. [Lasiver](http://cl.ly/image/003T183w0D17) - 'a' is different. Workaday is very different as well. [Crique](http://cl.ly/image/1K060G3E3B2F) - the 'k' is different. Equip isn't a bad alternative; nice that it's free, but it's definitely different.